# Trying to understand : in ruby and how it aligns with this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-forgery

I am coming from Pyton programming language and understood and can read C/C++. However, I have only been working on ruby for a few weeks and I am having trouble reading more complex codes in rails.

I see there's a lot of documentation, blogs, and references to ':' after the variable in ruby, from what I researched and read this is a symbol. I thought I understood the basic concept of this, but I get very confused when I read through the rails code of **application_controller.rb**

I am try to determine how this ties in with this code. I'm assuming **protect_from_forgery with: :exception** is a function that is passing in arguments with: and :exception?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raisng an exception 
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

I am reading the documentation on https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html. And trying to go through rails tutorials, but I am getting stuck understanding this sytnax of ruby.

Comment: Parentheses for arguments to a method are optional. So `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` is the same as, `protect_from_forgery( with: :exception )`.  `protect_from_forgery` accepts a hash as an argument. In Ruby a hash can be written as `{ :key1 => value1, :key2 = value2, ...}` or `{ key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}` (here, I am using symbols for keys). So the call is the same as `protect_from_forgery( { with: :exception } )`. Finally, when passing the has as an argument this way, Ruby lets you drop the brackets without adding ambiguity, so: `protect_from_forgery with: :exception`.

Comment: @lurker I think there's enough formatting and content there to warrant an answer rather than cramming it into a comment :p

Answer (score 1):

The protect from forgery method, as you have correctly mentioned,takes an optional hash argument. 
So essentially, it translates to

```
protect_from_forgery({with: :exception})
```

You can check the implementation of the method in the following link

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b738f1930f3c82f51741ef7241c1fee691d7deb2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L135

Comment: Or better (maybe): `protect_from_forgery({ :with => :exception })`. The "sometimes a Symbol has a leading colon and sometimes a trailing colon" part can be very confusing.

Comment: @muistooshort I still detest the (uh...) new hash format when both key and value are symbols :/